Is there a way to define `Eq` for this free group implementation (without implementing it twice)?
I have defined a free group type as follows:
{-# Language RankNTypes #-}
{-# Language ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# Language KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Kind

newtype Free (s :: Type -> Constraint) (a :: Type)
  = Free
    { runFree ::
      forall g. s g => (a -> g) -> g
    }

class Monoid m => Group m where
  inverse :: m -> m

type FreeGroup =
  Free Group

Attempt This Online!
This is the "natural" definition of a free group.
A bunch of instances are easy:
instance Functor (Free s)
instance Applicative (Free s)
instance Monad (Free s)
instance Semigroup (Free Group a)
instance Monoid (Free Group a)
instance Group (Free Group a)

(Definitions are included in the link above.)
However I want to implement an instance of Eq, and I'm sort of struggling. I have the following method which should work:

Implement a free group "structured" free group type, for which Eq is easy. This would be a list with each entry tagged as either an positive or negative generator.
Implement, Semigroup, Monoid, Group, and Eq for that type. (Functor and Applicative too for good measure.)
Use runFree pure with that group as the target to convert from the natural free group into the structured free group. Use the Eq instance on the structured free group to compare.

However if this is the real best method, then I feel like I should probably just be using the structured type in the first place. It's not just Eq, Eq seems more of a harbinger of a general difficulty I'm having with this type.
But I must admit I find the natural definition more aesthetically pleasing and I don't like the headache of potentially invalid state that the structured definition brings (e.g. [(True, 1), (False, 1)] is invalid since inverses are adjacent).
So I thought I'd ask here. Is there a way I could write an Eq instance without defining an additional version of the type to do the computations with?

A possibly useful warmup is to dial things all the way back: is there a way to write Eq for Free Magma beyond reifying a tree of operations? (I sort of doubt it, both for the Magma version and the Group version, though I don't exactly have a proof of this.)

This doesn't actually stop invalid states right? Since the requirement that inverse is actually the inverse is not enforced. So this is no better than using a usual ADT.

@Trebor Yes, you could theoretically distinguish between pure () <> inverse (pure ()) and Free (const mempty) by injecting into a group which doesn't satisfy the group laws. Whether this constitutes invalid state seems to be a bit subjective to me. I think the main distinction is that with a structured type you need to consider invalid state, reductions etc. every time you work with the algebraic structure, whereas this gives you the promise that as long as you don't intentionally inject into a bad group you won't have an issue.

Perhaps "Coroutining Folds with Hyperfunctions" by Launchbury, Krstic, and Sauerwein would be of interest to you.

To say a tiny bit more: I was all set to write up an answer just saying that there's no standard trick here. But as I tried to say why, I realized there is a closely-related trick: fusion. If we can reify and then recursively check for equality, perhaps we could manually fuse those two functions. Since (==) takes two arguments, the fusion would have to bounce back and forth between the two implicit structures. Oleg has a trick for doing zip with foldr, so I reviewed how it works, and decided it wasn't super relevant. However he lists this paper as an alternative approach.
